# ElasticSearch nested object query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jhipster

I'm using Elasticsearch provided by JHipster. I have made relation between entities, but I can't search by field in relation.

Eg. My model looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "text": "",
    "content": "",
    "time": 0,
    "thumbnailUrl": "",
    "stepsGroup": {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "",
      "imgUrl": "",
      "groupOrder": 0
    }
  }
]
```

And I would like to search like this:

```
query = stepsGroup.id: whatever
```

But actually it doesn't work. What should I enter in query to search what I want.

Comment: And this `query = stepsGroup.id: whatever` comes from where? Is this supposed to be an URL or it comes from your app or something else?

Comment: `it doesn't work` please, give some examples: what you have in ES, what you searched for and what was the result!